# Cannot convert from const TiXmlString to const std::string&

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, sdl, tinyxml

I am willing to make a 2D game with SDL and I am following a Shaun Mitchell's book. But I faced serious difficulties with this user-defined type conversion error when trying to compile my project...

Also, I am unfamiliar with this topic. I've watched some tutorials and searched the web for a solution.

Do I need to add

```
operator std::string&() const { return ???;}
```

to the tinyxmlstr.h in TiXmlString class? If so, how to implement it? What should I return?

[The Errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Zc0.png)

If I don't define the STL (which I use) in tinyxml.h, the compiler then returns a linkage error.

`Error  19  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __cdecl TiXmlNode::~TiXmlNode(void)" (??1TiXmlNode@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl TiXmlDocument::~TiXmlDocument(void)" (??1TiXmlDocument@@UEAA@XZ)`

[Without STL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ady8b.png)

StateParser class and implementation is the same as the one in the book.

Finally, if I have a mistake somewhere, how to debug it properly and where to look for it? Thank you, in advance!

Comment: Put all relevant info in your question, not in images linked somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear: non conversion available from `const TiXmlString` to `const std::string &`.

According to [this page](http://tinyxpath.sourceforge.net/doc/classTiXmlString.html), if I'm not wrong, there isn't even a direct conversion from `TiXmlString` to a `std::string`

I suppose you can write a method like this (exactly like the `value()` that return a `const char *`)

```
std::string valueStr () cont 
 { return value.c_str(); }
```

but in this way you return a copy of `value` (so return a `const std::string`, instead a plain `std::string`, is useless), not a reference. I don't know if this it's OK for you.

Comment: Thank you this fixed some of the errors. And left me with only the binary operator error, so I wrote an operator=
`TiXmlString& operator = (const std::string& copy)
 {
  return assign(copy.c_str(),copy.length());
 }` like this. It worked but now there is another error 
`Error 1 error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code 2. `

Comment: Excuse me but I have too little informations to be able to figure out where the new error may be. I can only tell you that your `operator=` seem right to me (although I would have written this way `TiXmlString& operator = (const std::string& copy) { assign(copy.c_str(),copy.length()); return *this; }`)